Maven artifact 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:RELEASE' cannot be resolved in external repositores
I successfully install DBeaver application in my windows 10 laptop. And connecting to a database need a driver to be installed first.
But the problems is that the drivers com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:RELEASE cannot be installed. It displays an error:

Maven artifact 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:RELEASE' cannot be
resolved in external repositores

I already allowed the app to run through windows firewall.
Run the application as Administrator.
